# referring to sheets instead of active worksheet in macro (on mac)

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code that adjusts the amount in the inventory.
The only thing I can't do is referring it to sheets.

```
Sub TESTEST()
For Each cl In Columns(8).SpecialCells(2).Offset(1).SpecialCells(2)
```

So the top part is located in sheet2

```
Columns(3).Find(cl.Value).Offset(, 1) = Columns(3).Find(cl.Value).Offset(, 1) - cl.Offset(, 1)
Next cl
```

The Bottom is located in sheet3

So, in short, my inventory list is in sheet3 and the product receipt in sheet 2. with every purchase it will change the amount in the inventory

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: in the bottom is sheet3 on both sides of = ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to provide more detail on how you are assigning in the bottom part, also add a test to ensure there are some cells to copy. That said, maybe something like:

```
Sub TESTEST()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

        For Each cl In .Columns(8).SpecialCells(2).Offset(1).SpecialCells(2)
          ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns(3).Find(cl.Value).Offset(, 1) = .Columns(3).Find(cl.Value).Offset(, 1) - cl.Offset(, 1)
        Next cl

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Sub TEST()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
        For Each Cl In .Columns(1).SpecialCells(2).Offset(1).SpecialCells(2)
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Columns(3).Find(Cl.Value).Offset(, 1) = Columns(3).Find(Cl.Value).Offset(, 1) - Cl.Offset(, 1)
        Next Cl
    End With
End Sub